# remove dictionaire from list if ALL values are empty string

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaires (all dictionaires in the list have the same 9 keys) and I would like to delete the dictionaires on the list where the value of the 9 keys is   ' '. But if at least one key have a value it would keep the whole dictionaire (including the other keys where it is ' ' )

For example (with only 3 keys to simplify)

```
[{Key1:JJ, Key2:GG, Key3:''},{Key1:'', Key2:'', Key3:''},{Key1:'', Key2:GG, Key3:''},{Key1:'', Key2:'', Key3:''}]
```

The output would be

```
[{Key1:JJ, Key2:GG, Key3:''},{Key1:'', Key2:GG, Key3:''}]
```

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `any()`:

```
[d for d in inputlist if any(d.itervalues())]
```

Use `any(d.values())` in Python 3.

`any()` only returns `True` if there are any non-empty values in the input list. By using `d.itervalues()` we test the minimal number of values in the dictionary to prove there is a non-empty value among them.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [{'Key1': 'JJ', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key3':''}, {'Key1': '', 'Key2': '', 'Key3': ''}, {'Key1': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key3': ''}, {'Key1': '', 'Key2': '', 'Key3': ''}]
>>> [d for d in inputlist if any(d.itervalues())]
[{'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': 'JJ'}, {'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': ''}]
```

If any values *other* than the empty strings could be tested as false as well (such as `None` or `0`), you can use an explicit test as well:

```
[d for d in inputlist if any(v != '' for v in d.itervalues())]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the keys based on what is returned by [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)*:

```
>>> dct = [{'Key1':'JJ', 'Key2':'GG', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'', 'Key2':'', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'',
'Key2':'GG', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'', 'Key2':'', 'Key3':''}]
>>> [x for x in dct if any(y != '' for y in x.values())]
[{'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': 'JJ'}, {'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': ''}]
>>>
```

---

Or, if the values are all strings, then you can just do this:

```
>>> dct = [{'Key1':'JJ', 'Key2':'GG', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'', 'Key2':'', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'',
'Key2':'GG', 'Key3':''},{'Key1':'', 'Key2':'', 'Key3':''}]
>>> [x for x in dct if any(x.values())]
[{'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': 'JJ'}, {'Key3': '', 'Key2': 'GG', 'Key1': ''}]
>>>
```

This works because empty strings evaluate to `False` in Python.

---

*Note:  If you are on Python 2.x, you should use [`dict.itervalues`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) in place of `dict.values`.  It is more efficient because it returns an iterator instead of a list.